# How to use Obfs4Proxy

Tags: obfs4

Right now I'm using obfs3,obfs2 and b64 with my OpenVPN server and sadly they are slow in my country (Iran)

These obfuscation methods are slow at morning and they get fast at after noon (I don't know why but i think it's my government doing this, I think because internet speed in after noon is slow enough and they turn off their firewall to don't make it slower)

But when i used obfs4 in Tor browser i saw it's pretty fast
So let me know how i can change my commands for obfs4

I know how to install obfs4proxy in my ubuntu server and windows client i just need to run write commands

In my ubuntu 14.04 server i run

```
obfsproxy obfs3 --dest=127.0.0.1:1194 server 0.0.0.0:532
```

and in my windows client i run

```
obfsproxy --no-log obfs3 socks 127.0.0.1:21025
```

So how to convert them?